# C# - ComboBox control of ASP.NET AJAX control is not editable in Chrome

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

We dynamically create a web page with an editable dropdown list. But it can't be edited in Chrome, it did work in IE. Following are the dynamically creating code and result on page.

```
 AjaxControlToolkit.ComboBox comboBox = GetComboBox(i);
 sControlID = comboBox.ID;
 comboBox.TabIndex = (short)(i + 100);
 if (ca.List != null)
 {
      string[] sList = ca.List;
      Array.Sort(sList);
      for (int j = 0; j < sList.Length; j++)
            comboBox.Items.Add(sList[j]);
      }
      ListItem li = comboBox.Items.FindByText(sVal);
      if (li != null)
            li.Selected = true;
      else
      {
           li = new ListItem(sVal);
           comboBox.Items.Add(li);
           li.Selected = true;
           }
      tc.Controls.Add(comboBox);
}
```

[image]

I found following snippet at the bottom oft the page within `script` tag,

```
Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
$create(Sys.Extended.UI.ComboBox, {"autoCompleteMode":3,"autoPostBack":true,"buttonControl":$get("comboBox2_comboBox2_Button"),"comboTableControl":$get("comboBox2_comboBox2_Table"),"dropDownStyle":1,"hiddenFieldControl":$get("comboBox2_comboBox2_HiddenField"),"optionListControl":$get("comboBox2_comboBox2_OptionList"),"selectedIndex":4,"textBoxControl":$get("comboBox2_comboBox2_TextBox")}, null, null, $get("comboBox2"));
});
```

As you can see, the `textBoxControl` in the snippet is the text filed for this editable dropdown list. If I remove it(`"textBoxControl":$get("comboBox2_comboBox2_TextBox")`) from the snippet, it can be edited but the button behind is not working, it means the dropdown list doesn't work.

Any ideas what's going on here? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

I figured that it's the Ajax Control Toolkit, I think that the snippet I posted is the key for this issue. When the page loads, it changes and overrides the original element. I checked the document about this control and found that the dropDownStyle is for controlling the permission to allow user to edit or not. But as the document says, there are three values which are 'DropDownList', 'DropDown' and 'Simple'. But it didn't work when I changed this value.

Comment: Frist step, what console errors, if any, do you get in Chrome? Alos please provide the code that you use to create the Combo.

Comment: No console errors.

Comment: Do you know what's this snippet for?

Comment: Until you add the code on how you created the ComboBox I would be guessing as ASP.net does not include a ComboBox by default. I would **guess** that it is part of what the .net Ajax control toolkit injects into the page, or Telrik, or whatever controls are being used here. Again, please include *your* code.

Comment: I just figured out that it's the `Ajax Control Toolkit`, I think that the snippet I posted is the key for this issue. When the page loads, it changes and overrides the original element (it's standard ASP.NET ComboBox). I checked the document about this control and found that the `dropDownStyle` is for controlling the permission to allow user to edit or not. But as the document says, there are three values which are 'DropDownList', 'DropDown' and 'Simple'. But it didn't work when I changed this value. Are you familiar with this?

Comment: Again I ask you to please show your code!

Comment: How about including it as code and not an image so we don't have to type it in line by line? I Suggest you read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117375/discussion-between-sky-and-jon-p).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thank for @Jon P's help.

Finally I find some clues [here](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/27215). It's caused by the mismatch of the version between ComboBox Control and Chrome.

It works in version 47.xxx of Chrome (my version for testing), not sure if it works in newer version, it doesn't work with latest version (51.xxx).